# How to load another FXML file into the scene when using fx:Include

Tags: java, initialization, javafx-8, fxml, controllers

I have a root element of my app and currently two FXML files (with separate Controllers both connected to a MainController class) placed inside the layout using `fx:include`. Lets say i click a button and i want to load a new FXML file placed on the root element instead of one of the previous layout components, preferrably put on the root element in the same way as the other components with`fx:include` and with a controller that is initialized before or after the FXML file is loaded and connected to the MainController class. How would i go about this?

Cheers

Comment: Just load the FXML (using an `FXMLLoader`) in the button's event handler code... Can you show some code showing what you have tried?